# Creating opportunity line from SalesforceSharp

Tags: rest-api, opportunity-lineitem, pricebookentry

I am using SalesforceSharp to create an Opportunity.  The header is working OK, I have ensured that the `CurrencyIsoCode` and `PriceBook2Id` fields are set.

When trying to create the Opportunity Line Item, I am getting the error message below:

```
field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId, unknown (versions 3.0 and higher must specify pricebook entry id, others must specify product id)
```

When creating the object I am passing in the `OpportunityId`, `PriceBookEntryId`, and `Quantity`.  I have tried various combinations of using `Product2Id`, and also using `Product Code` and `Total Price`.

I have checked that the Opportunity has a valid Price Book connected, and can create the item manually.

If I change to pass the `Product2Id` in, I get a different error message:

```
field integrity exception: PricebookEntryId (pricebook entry currency code does not match opportunity currency code)
```

I have four entries in my Price Book for the same product with different currencies.  I have found that if I select them using the Developer Console, the JPY entry is first.  And looking at a validation rule in the Logs I can see that it indeed is finding the JPY entry.

Questions:

1. Approach 1, when it is referring to v3 - v3 of what?
2. Approach 2, what field am I missing on the Opportunity Line for it to find the correct PriceBook entry?

Comment: I've no experience with C#, but "v3" is likely referring to the Salesforce API version. A quick dive through the SalesforceSharp codebase reveals that they use v28.0 by default (which is 8 years old at this point, the newest API version is 52.0). Do you ever set/change the value of `SalesforceClient.ApiVersion`?

Comment: The version is set to match my sandbox which is currently at v51.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pricebook entry currency code does not match opportunity currency code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85372/pricebook-entry-currency-code-does-not-match-opportunity-currency-code)

Comment: No i reviewed that and it looks like they were creating the price book entry in code. In my scenario i am pointing to an existing price book entry.

Comment: Same idea for existing - you need to retrieve the correct PricebookEntry record based on your target opp's currency and product (Product2). Mismatch leads to the error message you've encountered.

Comment: I have reviewed all Id fields by selecting them in developer console and it is all looking ok.  Dont think its a salesforcesharp issue as i use this for other items (account, etc) with lookup fields and it works perfectly.